# Flink Datastream to Table

Tags: apache-flink

I am trying to run this

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eg7r5.png)

but i can't understand the dollar symbol and what Table class need to import in my project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly which imports you will need depends a bit on which version of Flink you are using, but these are what I'm using with Flink 1.12 and the blink sql planner:

```java
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment;
import org.apache.flink.table.api.Table;
import org.apache.flink.table.api.bridge.java.StreamTableEnvironment;

import static org.apache.flink.table.api.Expressions.$;
```

The dollar symbol is, in fact, the dollar symbol: `$`. It comes from the last of the imports shown above.

Comment: I am using Flink 1.11.1 maybe this is the problem? i will try with 1.12 thanks a lot!

Comment: I think it should work with 1.11. Sorry, I had left off the critical import.

Comment: Very helpful answer. Flink's documentation sucks. There's no mention of this anywhere.